# How do I do a line break with SVG text element ?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Using D3 to create a force graph. I wish to click a button and a rectangle appears (which I have done).
Now I want to append this rectangles text with a few lines of text.

I have three sentences I wish to show, one on each line, so I know where the line breaks should be.

I have tried these :

```
.text("test" + "\n" + "should be on second line");

.text("test" + "\\n" + "should be on second line");

.text("test" + "<br/>" + "should be on second line");

.html("test" + "\n" + "should be on second line");

.html("test" + "\\n" + "should be on second line");

.html("test" + "<br/>" + "should be on second line");
```

None of them seem to work and I am unsure why. I have searched around and people are sort of doing hacks to get around this. Surely there is an easier way ?

Comment: is it http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045 ?

Comment: yeah @NitishKumar but that doesnt really matter. All I want to do is edit the text on a svg:rect to have text on multiple lines

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991171/auto-line-wrapping-in-svg-text

Comment: Why do quesitons on this tag never get closed, this has been asked so many times... [How to linebreak an svg text in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447321/how-to-linebreak-an-svg-text-in-javascript)

Comment: @Mark I was looking to see if there was an easier way since I couldnt find one. But ended up hacking it abit in the end as there isnt an easy way.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured it out and works for me as I am using D3. I created an array (of the text I wish to show), then made a function that splits the array up on seperate lines.

```
var popUpTextArray = ["first line", "second line", "third line"];

function textMultipleRows(textArray, area, xPos, yPos){

    for(i=0;i<textArray.length;i++){
        d3.selectAll(area) //-area you wish to append the text to
        .append("text")
        .classed("popUpTextLeft", true) //-CSS class for the text
        .attr("x", xPos)
        .attr("y", yPos+(i*20)) //-new line when going through the loop
        .text(textArray[i]); //-goes through each element in the text array
    }   
}

textMultipleRows(popUpTextArray, "#window1", 300,200);
```

It is a bit hacky and it's made up of D3 so I dont know if alot of people will use it but as I said it works perfectly for me.