# Replace space with new line charcter in texts d3js

Tags: d3.js, svg, text, newline, bubble-chart

I have a script in which I make txts in the following way:

```
texts = svg.selectAll(null)
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.abbreviation;
      })
      .attr("pointer-events", "none")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", "10px")
      .attr("fill", "black");

    texts.each(function(d) {
        console.log(this.getComputedTextLength());
        d.size = this.getComputedTextLength() / 2 ;
    });

    simulation.nodes(data).on("tick", function() {
        circles.attr("cx", function(d) {
                return d.x = Math.max(20, Math.min(width - 20, d.x));
            })
            .attr("cy", function(d) {
                return d.y = Math.max(20, Math.min(height - 20, d.y));
            })
        texts.attr("x", function(d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return d.y;
            });
    });
```

I am using property abbreviation in data to put text over the bubbles but I want to replace all spaces in input with new line character.

I tried some soutions like given at this link: [How to linebreak an svg text in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447321/how-to-linebreak-an-svg-text-in-javascript)
but all texts go to left most corner or if I remove the .attr("x", 0) property from this, then the alignment of texts in not right. See picture below:

[image]

"State" should come directly below "Iowa"

Updated script:

```
 texts = svg.selectAll(null)
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .each(function (d) {
         var arr = d.abbreviation.split(" ");
         for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         d3.select(this).append("tspan")
        .text(arr[i])
        .attr("dy", i ? "1.2em" : 0)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("class", "tspan" + i);
      }
    })
      .attr("pointer-events", "none")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", "10px")
      .attr("fill", "black");
```

What should I do to make the alignment right or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to fix this. An easy one is appending the `<tspan>` to a `<g>` element, setting all their `x` properties to `0` and `text-anchor` to `middle`.

Have a look at the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = [{
  text: "some text"
}, {
  text: "a longer text here"
}, {
  text: "an even longer text here"
}, {
  text: "short text"
}, {
  text: "a long text"
}];

var texts = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g");

texts.append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .each(function(d) {
    var arr = d.text.split(" ");
    d3.select(this).selectAll(null)
      .data(arr)
      .enter()
      .append("tspan")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("dy", function(d, i) {
        return "1.2em"
      })
      .text(String)
  })

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(200, 100))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(40))
  .on("tick", tick);

function tick() {
  texts.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="250"></svg>
```

PS: Don't use that `for` loop inside the `each`. That's not *idiomatic* D3. Instead of that, just use an enter selection (refer to the demo to see how to do it).

Comment: This works perfectly fine. Thank you so much.
 The other solution that you had provided for text size isn't working anymore: 

texts.each(function(d) {
 d.size = this.getComputedTextLength() / 2 ;
});